# Express the field $X(x,y) =(-y,x)$ of $\mathbb{S}^1$ in terms of a known atlas.

Tags: smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

This is what I've done:

$$X(x,y) = -y\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + x \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$$

Consider the chart $(U,\varphi)$ , where: $$U=\mathbb{S}^1 - N$$  $$\varphi (x,y)=\frac{x}{1-y}  \equiv u$$. Then:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial }{\partial u} = \frac{1}{1-y} \frac{\partial}{\partial u}$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial }{\partial u} = \frac{x}{(1-y)^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial u}$$

So:

$$X = \frac{-y}{1-y} \frac{\partial}{\partial u} + \frac{x^2}{(1-y)^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial u}=\frac{-y+y^2+x^2}{(1-y)^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial u}=\frac{-1}{1-y} \frac{\partial}{\partial u}$$

Where I have used that $x^2+y^2=1$.

However, I have not been able to express $X$ exclusively in terms of $u$.

Comment: Consider the map $(U,\arctan_2(x,y)); U=\mathbb{S}-\{(-1,0)\}$ and $\vartheta=\arctan_2(x,y)$. Then $X=\partial_{\vartheta}$

Comment: @GabrieleCassese thanks for your comment. Didn't know about that atlas on $\mathbb{S}^1$, its nice how simple the expression of $X$ on it is.